# Determine the last visible row in Microsoft Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with a fixed number of visible rows. I want to write a macro to insert a row after the last visible row.

To do so I first want to determine what the current last visible row is. I tried to write the following but I get a compilation error. I don't know VB very well so I'm properly doing something wrong in the While loop.

Thanks.

```
Sub AddRequirementRule()
Dim rowNumber As Long
rowNumber = 1
While (Not ActiveSheet.Row(rowNumber).Hidden)
   rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
End While


MsgBox (rowNumber)
```

On a side note, where can I find more information about the error in Excel's Macro editor (VBA 7.0)?

Comment: Do you mean the last visible row that contains data??  Usually there are many,many visible blank rows at the bottom of a worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it won't work that way.
Try to check this way to avoid the compile error:

```
While (Not thisworkbook.Sheets(1).range("A" & rowNumber).entirerow.hidden)
   rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
Wend
```

For more info on errors, I suggest that you use error handling. 
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: I need to use ActiveSheet because I do not know which sheet I'm on.

Comment: Although you should definitely know which sheet you're on and what sheet object you're currently handling -> therefore avoiding Activesheet and naming your sheet objects. But well, that's for another day to discuss.

Comment: Actually you are absolutely right since I don't reuse this Sub in other sheets...

Answer (score 0):

My script is simply wrong. I shouldn't use `End While` but rather `Wend`.

I also had to do what Kim recommended: `Range("A" & rowNumber).EntireRow.Hidden` instead of `Row(rowNumber).Hidden`.

Here's the correct code:

```
Sub AddRequirementRule()
Dim rowNumber As Long
rowNumber = 1
While (Not ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rowNumber).EntireRow.Hidden)
   rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
Wend


MsgBox (rowNumber)


End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Oops, indeed, I've adapted this in my code as well. It is either Do While... loop, Do ... Loop Until or While...Wend.